# No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for akka.actor.typed.ActorRef[org.knoldus.eventSourcing.UserState.Confirmation]

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, play-json

> No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for akka.actor.typed.ActorRef[org.knoldus.eventSourcing.UserState.Confirmation] in the implicit scope (Hint: if declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before)
>
> [error]   implicit val userCommand: Format[AddUserCommand] = Json.format

I am getting this error even though I have made Implicit instance of Json `Format` for `AddUserCommand`.

Here is my code:

```scala
trait UserCommand extends CommandSerializable
    
object AddUserCommand{
  implicit val format: Format[AddUserCommand] = Json.format[AddUserCommand]
}
    
final case class AddUserCommand(user:User, reply: ActorRef[Confirmation]) extends UserCommand
```

Can anyone please help me with this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gael noted, you need to provide a `Format` for `ActorRef[Confirmation]`.  The complication around this is that the natural serialization, using [the ActorRefResolver](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/serialization.html#serializing-actorrefs) requires that an `ExtendedActorSystem` be present, which means that the usual approaches to defining a `Format` in a companion object won't quite work.

Note that because of the way Lagom does dependency injection, [this approach doesn't really work in Lagom: commands in Lagom basically can't use Play JSON](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/scala/UsingAkkaPersistenceTyped.html#Data-Serialization).

```scala
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.adapter.ClassicActorSystemOps
import play.api.libs.json._

class PlayJsonActorRefFormat(system: ExtendedActorSystem) {
  def reads[A] = new Reads[ActorRef[A]] {
    def reads(jsv: JsValue): JsResult[ActorRef[A]] =
      jsv match {
        case JsString(s) => JsSuccess(ActorRefResolver(system.toTyped).resolveActorRef(s))
        case _ => JsError(Seq(JsPath() -> Seq(JsonValidationError(Seq("ActorRefs are strings"))))) // hopefully parenthesized that right...
      }
  }

  def writes[A] = new Writes[ActorRef[A]] {
    def writes(a: ActorRef[A]): JsValue = JsString(ActorRefResolver(system.toTyped).toSerializationFormat(a))
  }

  def format[A] = Format[ActorRef[A]](reads, writes)
}
```

You can then define a format for `AddUserCommand` as

```scala
object AddUserCommand {
  def format(arf: PlayJsonActorRefFormat): Format[AddUserCommand] = {
    implicit def arfmt[A]: Format[ActorRef[A]] = arf.format

    Json.format[AddUserCommand]
  }
}
```

Since you're presumably using JSON to serialize the messages sent around a cluster (otherwise, the `ActorRef` shouldn't be leaking out like this), you would then construct an instance of the format in your Akka Serializer implementation.

(NB: I've only done this with Circe, not Play JSON, but the basic approach is common)

Comment: yeah I understand the process now and thank you for efforts. But I am getting this:- Type mismatch. Required: Reads[ActorRef[A]], found: JsValue => JsResult[ActorRef[A]]. in def format[A] = Format[ActorRef[A]](reads, writes)

Comment: Missed a `{`... the joys of coding in the SO text box... edititng now

Answer (score 0):

The error says that it cannot construct a `Format` for `AddUserCommand` because there's no `Format` for `ActorRef[Confirmation]`.

When using `Json.format[X]`, all the members of the case class `X` must have a `Format` defined.

<del>In your case, you probably don't want to define a formatter for this case class (serializing an `ActorRef` doesn't make much sense) but rather build another case class with data only.</del>

Edit: See Levi's answer on how to provide a formatter for `ActorRef` if you really want to send out there the actor reference.

Comment: Okay I get what you are saying but can this can be solved if I provide Serialisation of ActorRef[Confirmation] ?

Comment: Yes but that's not what you should do. How are you going to (de)serialize it?

Comment: ActorRef's are designed for serialization (Akka provides some built in means to represent an `ActorRef` as an opaque string)

Comment: Oh okay, didn't know that. Will edit my answer accordingly then even though yours is more complete.